# Let $f(x)=e^x+x^3+x-3$. This function is invertible. What is the value of $f^{-1}(-2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

I am having trouble with this question. I don't have any calculus background.

I think $f^{-1}$ means the inverse of $f(x)$

Does that mean I have to find the inverse of $f(x)$ first? But again, I am trapped when operating the e because there is also $x^3$ and $x$. I cannot think of a way to isolate them.

Comment: You don't need to find $f^{-1}$ explicitly. You just need to find an $x$ such that $e^x  + x^3 + x - 3 = 2$. The point is, that such an $x$ is unique, because that LHS as a function is one-one. Such an $x$ is easy to find, try the first few values you can think of.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It is easy to find that $\;x\;$ because the right side in that equation you wrote is actually $\;-2\;$ . If it were $\;2\;$ that'd be a rather tough equation whose solution could only be approximated (or esle use the Lambert $\;W\;$  function or stuff).

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for pointing that out : the explicit expression for $f^{-1}$ is not easy to find.

Answer (score 5):

We can just nuzzle around and find some $x$ wifh $f(x)=-2$, then $f^{-1}(-2)=x$. $x=0$ works – and, as it turns out, the function is increasing everywhere so this is the *only* solution.

Answer (score 0):

A function needs to have  domain and Range (co-domain) defined. But here these are not given so we can take it as $f:R\to R$, it being increasing as $f'(x)=e^x+3x^2+1>0, \forall x \in R$. it is one to one. As $f(-\infty)=-\infty, f(\infty)=+\infty$, it is onto. Hence, it is a bijection so the inverse exists, but it is not obtainable. Noting that $f(0)=-2$ we can claim that $f^{-1}(-2)=0$. $f^{-1}(e-1)=1$ but we cannot find $f^{-1}(2)$ by hand, though it exist and it is numerically obtainable as $f^{-1}(2)=1.04084...$ similarly one can find $f^{-1}(0)=0.68723$. See the plot of $f(x)$ below

[image]